# How do I get icon balloon tips instead of notification slide outs

Tags: c++, winapi, tooltip, system-tray

I'm creating a program that will be an icon in the in the system tray's notification area and I can't get the balloon tips to appear.

The notify icon balloon messages, like NIN_BALLOONSHOW, are being received okay, but I get a tool tip that slides out from the right edge of the screen instead of the old balloons that I need. Win10-1809 is likely intercepting the messages and changing their  behavior. As you can tell, i'm using c++.

How can I change this and get the old balloons back?

Edit: I've found a way to do it in the registry, but I need a way to do it with code.

More data:

Here are pieces of what I'm doing:

```
  // initial tooltip code
NOTIFYICONDATA  nid;
nid.cbSize           = sizeof(nid);
nid.hWnd             = hwnd;
nid.uID              = 1;
nid.uFlags           = NIF_ICON | NIF_TIP | NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_SHOWTIP;
nid.uVersion         = NOTIFYICON_VERSION_4;
nid.uCallbackMessage = WMAPP_NOTIFYCALLBACK;

LoadIconMetric(g_hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MYICON
               LIM_SMALL, &nid.hIcon);
LoadString(g_hInst, IDS_MYTOOLTIP, nid.szTip, ARRAYSIZE(nid.szTip));

Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &nid);
Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_SETVERSION, &nid);
```

Then later in the code when I want balloons:

```
  // balloon code
nid.uFlags           = NIF_INFO;
nid.dwInfoFlags      = NIIF_WARNING;

LoadString(g_hInst, IDS_BALLOON_TITLE, nid.szInfoTitle,
           ARRAYSIZE(nid.szInfoTitle));
LoadString(g_hInst, IDS_BALLOON_TEXT, nid.szInfo, ARRAYSIZE(nid.szInfo));
LoadIconMetric(g_hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_BALLOON), LIM_LARGE,
               &nid.hBalloonIcon);

Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_MODIFY, &nd);
```

Comment: Doubt there's anything you can do about this. The OS implements the notification system and in Windows 10 that has changed from tooltips to the slideout message.

Comment: If you found a registry way, why not modify the registry programmatically?

Comment: I tried that, but the registry method requires a restart and I don't know if doing it programmatically for just this one program would also. I haven't gotten around to testing it yet. Stay tuned.